# How to assign a new value to top n rows in a subset using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, variable-assignment

I am trying to subset my datatable, select the top n rows, and assign them a new value.

My first attempt was as follows:

```
DT[condition_1 & condition_2][1:N][x := 1]
```

However datatable doesn't seem to let you pipe assignments like this, nor does it let you select the top rows (given multiple conditions) without piping.

My second attempt was as follows:

```
DT[intersect(which(condition_1 & condition_2), c(1:N)), x := 1]
```

This solves some of the issues but only works if the conditions happen to be passed in the top N rows of the table, and not the first N times the conditions were passed.

RE: Markus

For reference, I've come to this issue when trying to recreate a portfolio of the top 100 stocks by rank with a buffer rule, such that:

1, Rank < 80, automatically included;

2, Rank between 80 and 120, and member previous year, included;

3, Remaining spots filled by rank until membership totals 100 per year.

The following is a dummy version of my code with the issue line commented out and a smaller sample:

```
Example <- data.table("stock_id" = rep(LETTERS[1:20],20), "year" = rep(1999:2018,each=20),"zscore" = rnorm(400))
Example[,Rank:=rank(zscore),by=year]

Example[,membership := 0]
Example[year==min(year) & Rank <= 10, membership := 1]
Example[Rank<=5,membership := 1]
Example[,p_membership := shift(membership,n=1)]
setkey(Example,year,Rank)

n <- data.table(unique(Example[,year]))
n <- n[!(V1 == min(year))]

for (i in n[,V1]){
  Example[year == i & between(Rank, 6, 15) & p_membership == 1, membership := 1]
  N <- abs(10 - sum(Example[year == i, membership], na.rm=TRUE))
  #  Attempt 1 ---->     Example[year == i & membership ==0][1:N][membership := 1]
  #  Attempt 2 ---->     Example[intersect(which(year == i & membership ==0), c(1:N)), membership := 1]
    Example[,p_membership := shift(membership,n=1), by=gvkey]
}
```

With a solution for stock_id "A" being something like:

```
   stock_id year       zscore Rank membership p_membership
 1:        A 1999 -0.275206888   10          0           NA
 2:        A 2000  0.419941872   16          0            0
 3:        A 2001  0.002890563    9          0            0
 4:        A 2002 -1.464640431    2          1            0
 5:        A 2003 -1.701047022    1          1            1
 6:        A 2004 -0.252197958    4          1            1
 7:        A 2005  0.234173727   10          1            1
 8:        A 2006 -0.024872099   19          0            1
 9:        A 2007 -0.188246291   20          0            0
10:        A 2008 -0.267944869    6          1            0
11:        A 2009  0.728570748   12          1            1
12:        A 2010 -0.040244792   11          1            1
13:        A 2011  0.942448885   18          0            1
14:        A 2012 -0.051872395   11          0            0
15:        A 2013 -1.171291738    4          1            0
16:        A 2014  1.505583171   18          0            1
17:        A 2015  0.507555473   15          0            0
18:        A 2016 -0.310156393    9          1            0
19:        A 2017  0.713142517   14          1            1
20:        A 2018  2.196859750   20          0            1
```

Needless to say, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share `DT` or at least a subset of it so we can run your code? Also show expected output.

Comment: maybe something like `DT[DT[condition_1 & condition_2, head(.I, n)]$V1, x := 1]`

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
I can subset your dataset, and set a value to the added 'www' column, where the subset that is given by multiple conditions, is ordered by the decreasing values of the 'zscore' column.

Example[,'www' := 0] #create a new column
Example[stock_id == 'A' | year == 1999,][][order(-zscore)][1:2,'www'] <- 5

Comment: @MattHoldup Something like this? `library("data.table");
I <- data.table(iris);
I[Sepal.Length>5, myN:=.I][myN<15, x:=1]`